# ListView showing empty TextBlocks at runtime

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, data-binding, design-time

I'm experiencing a strange problem with data-binding. In the designer everything is shown correctly, but at runtime my ListView just contains those TextBlocks with an empty string in them. I'm using MVVM light for ViewModels. Most of the code was generated by VS2012 by creating a split page for WindowsStore-Apps.

Here's my XAML: ( I already removed some other parts, like the `VisualStateManager`, but without effect so that doesn't seem to be an issue.)

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage
    x:Name="pageRoot"
    x:Class="Kunden.OrderPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Kunden"
    xmlns:common="using:Kunden.Common"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    DataContext="{Binding SelectCustomersViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <Page.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource
            x:Name="itemsViewSource"
            Source="{Binding Items}"/>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="primaryColumn" Width="610"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid x:Name="titlePanel">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button
                x:Name="backButton"
                Click="GoBack"
                IsEnabled="{Binding DefaultViewModel.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}"
                Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Grid.Column="1" Text="Werbeauswahl" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}" Margin="0,0,-2,40"/>
        </Grid>

        <!-- Elementliste mit vertikalem Bildlauf -->
        <ListView
            x:Name="itemListView"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsListView"
            AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
            TabIndex="1"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Margin="-10,-10,0,0"
            Padding="120,0,0,60"
            IsSwipeEnabled="False"
            SelectionChanged="ItemListView_SelectionChanged"
            ItemsSource="{Binding AvaiableCountries}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
... closing brackets etc.
```

The `IEnumerable`I want to bind:

```
private IEnumerable<Country> avaiableCountries;

        public IEnumerable<Country> AvaiableCountries
        {
            get { return avaiableCountries; }
            set { avaiableCountries = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => AvaiableCountries); }
        }
```

The data value object `Country`I need for my LINQ-Query:

```
public class Country
    {
        internal string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try try changing the access modifier of the Name property from `internal` to `public` and see whether that fixes your problem?

If that doesn't work post the code where you're populating AvaiableCountries with data

Comment: too damn easy... changing it to public did the trick. I already did that but it seems I didn't try to run it with this change though...
strange thing, it was displayed in the designer though...